# remove the empty zero value layers in 3D matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

Initially I am get 3D matrix from below code

```
X = rand(100,100,10);
```

Now i am set zero like below code

```
X(:,:,3) =0;
X(:,:,4) =0;
```

Now i want to reshape the Matrix `X` to `100 * 100 * 8` . Means I want to remove the above two layers ( 3 and 4);

How can I do ?

Comment: Simply write `X(:,:,[3 4]) = [];`.

Comment: your code is not usefull for me . Is there any other option  ?

Comment: How come it is not useful? this is the matlab's way to "remove the empty zero value row in 3D matrix". Now if you want to detect the zero-value rows, it is another question.

Comment: `X = X(:,:,[1,2,5:end])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
x(:,:,3:4) = [];  %// Assigning the zero value layers to null
```

**Alternative, if you don't know which layers are zero layers:**

```
mask = any(any(x)); %// getting which layers are Non-zero Layers

x = x(:,:,mask);
```

Comment: is there any other option ?

Comment: Just to augment your answer, for general layer removal in any axis, something like  `foo = any(any(cube,3),2); `  will specify the dimensions to 'collapse' .